# [SELinux]where is the definition of FILE__READ constant?

Tags: selinux

I'm reading SELinux source code.
In `security/selinux/hook.c`, `FILE__READ` constant is used.
where is the definition of `FILE__READ` constant?
Linux Kernel version is `4.3`.

Comment: This is not a programming question and there is no other suitable site to move the question

Comment: It's in security/selinux/include/av_permissions.h , which is generated during build.

Comment: @nos During build? thank you very much.